# Title starting by "questioning"

Tags: grammar, phrasing

I'm writing an article which I entitled "Questioning theory X as the basis of theory Y".

I no native speaker and I would like to know if such phrasing is correct in English.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is perfectly fine.

"Questioning" here could be seen to be acting as a gerund (as in "Questioning X...: why this is important") or as a verb with elided subject (as in "I am questioning X...").

In the former case, your title would be a [gerund phrase](http://www.learning2grow.org/2011/02/17/types-of-sentence-fragments/), like the bold parts of the sentences below:

> A Gerund phrase is a fragment that uses a verb with an ‘ing’ ending
>   (please note: a gerund is NOT a verb!). This ‘ing’ ending makes the
>   gerund act like a noun: I like running. I like cake.
>
> - I earn money on the weekends, **washing dishes at the local diner**.
>     (comma optional)
> - **Hoping to get a job**, I put my resume on Craigslist.

Gerunds can start sentences, and gerund phrases are frequently used as titles.

If "questioning" is the verb sense, this is equally acceptable: it simply means the title has been shortened by omitting the subject and auxiliary ("I am" or similar), as WS2 has pointed out.

A number of book and article titles beginning with "Questioning" can be seen on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/#q=questioning+the&tbm=bks) and [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=questioning%20the&btnG=&as_sdt=1,5&as_sdtp=), such as

- *Questioning the Media*
- *Questioning the Millenium*
- "Questioning the evidence for Earth's oldest fossils"

Comment: Whilst your other examples are clearly gerunds I am not sure that the OP's example is. It seems to me 'questioning' is being used as a verb, the subject and auxiliary for which are elided. Had it been a short form of 'The questioning of theory x...'it would clearly be a gerund. But there is no preposition 'of'. So what are the elided words? They can only be 'I am' or 'One is' or 'We are', or something like that.

Comment: I have edited to make a case for either possibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is correct English, as far as headlines and article titles go. They are usually malformed and abbreviated for conciseness.

But you should be aware of the implication of the verb form you are using.

Questioning X as the basis of Y

Sounds like you are exploring the process of questioning and its implications to theory Y. If that's how you mean it, I think it is perfectly acceptable.

It has, however, a slightly vague undertone, i.e. you are not defining a clear goal, unlike for instance "Can questioning theory X serve as a basis for theory Y?" or more definitive "Theory Y's foundation lies in the questioning of theory Y".
But again, it depends on what you want it to sound like.

Comment: I took it to mean questioning whether X is the basis of Y, or challenging the assumption that it definitely is.

Comment: This question is useful. It allows me to precisely my thoughts. I've voted up and I don't understand the one who downvote it.

Comment: @ppr Indeed, people often don't explain their downvotes! (wasn't me btw :p - I think our two answers are complementary).

Comment: If you want to say what nxx is suggesting then 'questioning [...]' would be the wrong way to put it. Better to write 'Doubts about whether X is the basis of Y' or an actual question: 'Is X really the basis of Y?'.

Comment: @nxx's first comment. This just goes to show that the sentence is too vague and allows too many interpretations.

Comment: @ChristianBenesch Indeed. Depends on the content of the article! @ your first comment - can't see how it'd be wrong, but I think your suggestions are good alternatives.

Comment: @nxx. Not wrong, but I hadn't read it like that at all. That's what I meant with that it is too vague. You can easily form two opinions on what it means, as you and me have just demonstrated. Better to be precise, in the title especially. So I agree with your answer, it is grammatically correct, but is the sense conveyed very well?

Comment: @nxx I agree: this phrasing is too vague (but nonetheless correct).